# Adding .gitignore file to the project

Tags: git

Following is my scenario.

I am using windows 8 and have made a directory that is tracked by git.
Now to see some working of gitignore I have made a sample text file in notepad and saved it as .gitignore file and set it's type to all.
Then i committed this file to my repository.
Now I was expecting that when i will change some data of this file and git will not complain but git is still saying it as changing not staged yet with filename.

why is that?

I have read similar question on which guy used git checkout to discard file but then why .gitgnore didnot do it work solely?

I am asking it since there are some types of files like log files which keeps changing that we want to add to our project contained in git but dont want git to continuously complaining about it.

Comment: Git never ignores tracked files. Why would you add log files to your repo? Sounds like a (poor) solution to a different, unmentioned, and probably simple, problem.

Comment: Actually I learned  that log files,compiled files,jar files,database files and bunch like that should be taken as .gitignore.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because the file that you want to ignore is still followed by git. You need to remove the file from git using `git rm --cache FILENAME`